# How to align div blocks with variable width?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 div blocks and I could not align their edges on the same vertical line.

```css
    div {
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    
    #header {
        z-index:1;
        position:fixed;
        height: 50px;
        width: 95%;
        background-color:#999966;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display:block;
    }
    
    .left {
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        width:10%;
        height:300px;
        background-color:#cccc00;
        margin-top:60px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        
    }
    
    .right {
        position:relative;
        float:right;
        width:88%;
        height:300px;
        background-color:#66ffff;
        margin-top: 60px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    
    #footer{
        position:relative;
        height: 50px;
        background-color:#ff0099;
        clear:both;
        margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
```

```html
     <div id="header"></div>
      
     <div class="left"></div>
      
     <div class="right"></div>
     
     <div id="footer"></div>
```

here is the result:
[image]

If I change the width of header to 100%, it went pass the below divs:
[image]

How do I align div blocks with unknown width( depends on the user screen size ) on the same edge?

Comment: Can you provide html code too?

Comment: Check the header width and left+right width.. its not equal. then its not possible to get aligned consistently.. Try to change header width or sum of left and right width

Comment: the left is aligned, so it's only the right that needs to be. I notice that your header is width 95% - what happens if you change that to 100% ?

Comment: Dear all, I've added the html. The width of header is 95% because I was following a tutorial on internet, the example wrote 95%. I tried 100% and it didn't work either.

Comment: I've edited my answer, the reason 100% doesn't work is because your body has a standard margin which you still need to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the width property of the header to `100%` would align them in this case. Note that `100%` will only work if there are no margins on the child or paddings on the parent.

The `.left` and `.right` together are `98%` but because `.right` is set to `float:right;` they will still occupy the full width of `100%`.

If you want to rescale all of the divs at the same time, I would recommend adding a div that contains all of them and setting the width on that.

**EDIT**

In response to your edit, try setting the `margin` of `body` to `0`.

The body has a margin by default, the footer doesn't mind because its width is automatically calculated, but when explicitly setting the width of the header to 100% you force it out of the body margins.

It also doesn't matter for .left and .right because one is floated left and the other is floated right. The only thing that remains is your header, because it has `position: fixed;` it requires an explicit width. Setting it to 100% will not work because of the margin of the body. So remove the margin of the body.

http://jsfiddle.net/guu6y0gc/

Getting the margin back is a different problem, and I would suggest building the layout differently. I've set up an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/guu6y0gc/2/

What I did here was set the body margin to `10px`, and instead of setting the width of `#header` to 100% I stretch it between `left:10px` and `right:10px`. Now you can still have a margin, as long as `left` and `right` on `#header` are the same value.

Comment: Many thanks! I tried adding a div that contains all of them and it didn't work until I remove the header's fixed position setting, why is that? I want the header to keep it's position of the web.

Comment: Note that if you want to keep a body margin (e.g., 5px), then you can change the header width to `width: calc(100% - 10px);` (don't forget the spaces around the minus sign) and explicitly set the body margin to the value you want instead of relying on a default value.

Comment: Thanks. This knowledge will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sw1jma3m/)**

Changed header `width to 98%` as sum of `left and right width is 98%`

```
#header {
    z-index:1;
    position:fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 98%;
    background-color:#999966;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: This isn't correct, it only looks to be because the body has a margin which is pushing the header out. If you set body to margin:0; you will see the width needs to be 100% (or auto, or removed). http://jsfiddle.net/sw1jma3m/4/

Comment: yes, I know.. but didnt want to change op's code more.. Just gave idea that op have to change the width of header / left/right width

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="min-width:100%;min-height:5%;background-color:Red"></div>
<div style="min-width:100%;min-height:90%;display:inline-block">
    <div style="min-width:30%;max-width:30%;height:100%;background-color:Black;float:left"></div>
    <div style="min-width:70%;max-width:70%;height:100%;background-color:green;float:right"></div>
</div>
<div style="min-width:100%;min-height:5%;background-color:Blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes some width from font-size.
So you have to define

Add these extra css to your styles

```
#left, #right{
font-size:0;
float:left
}
```

So inner side, you can define the font-size